# Optimizing Keyboard Input in Pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am creating a very simple game using the pygame library in which the player moves a square around the screen with the arrow keys. Unfortunately, the response of the controls are proving to be a problem.

The controls work fine until you switch direction e.g. left to right. When the player switches direction, the square the player is controlling jars to a halt.

The code for the controls looks like this in my game:

```
def move(self, event):
    speed = 6
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.rect.x -= speed
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.rect.x += speed
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.rect.y += speed
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.rect.y -= speed
```

This method is located in a class called Block (I stole Block from the pygame docs) that just makes a sprite for the player alongside providing movement.

The function move() is actually called inside the main.py file like this:

```
while going:
    clock.tick(60)

    # event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            going = False

    # controller input
    player.move(event)
```

Where player is an instance of the Block class and event is just an item from the event queue of my game.

I tried using the pygame.key.get_pressed function (which did work better) but I would rather use the pygame.KEYDOWN locals alternatively because it returns the key presses as events in the event queue rather than booleans returned from a list.

If you are more investigative than your average joe you can take a look at the "full" game here: https://github.com/catmes/Project_React

You will need pygame 1.9.2 and python 2.7. Keep in my mind that the game itself is more a learning exercise so don't surprised when you see bad code (that will be fixed later of course ;) ).

Thanks for stopping by and giving this question a peek, I do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried out a smooth way to move around a player that works pretty well. It basically keeps track of the key presses in a list and moves the player based on the last key pressed. When you press a key it'll add a *speed* variable at the first position in the list, and when you release the key it'll remove that variable. In the *update* method you'll add the first speed variable of the list to corresponding x and y value.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (32, 32))
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.velocity = [0, 0]  # It's current velocity.
        self.speed = 4  # The speed the player will move.
        self.dx = []  # Keeps track of the horizontal movement.
        self.dy = []  # Keeps track of the vertical movement.

    def update(self):
        try:
            self.rect.x += self.dx[0]  # Index error if the list is empty.
        except IndexError:
            self.rect.x += 0
        try:
            self.rect.y += self.dy[0]  # Index error if the list is empty.
        except IndexError:
            self.rect.y += 0

player = Player()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.dx.insert(0, -player.speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.dx.insert(0, player.speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.dy.insert(0, -player.speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.dy.insert(0, player.speed)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.dx.remove(-player.speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.dx.remove(player.speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.dy.remove(-player.speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.dy.remove(player.speed)

    player.update()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    # print player.dx, player.dy  # Uncomment to see what's happening in action!
```

Comment: That works wonderfully! Thank you so much. I was tried keeping the state of the keys that were released  to see if that would optimize the controls but nothing to the extent that you did it. Cheers!

Comment: I was actually curious of how you defined your __init__ function in the Player class; is there a specific reason why you use super() to inherent  when you have previously defined an __init__ function inside the Player class?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. I used `super(Player, self).__init__()` to initialize the *superclass* `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. To do this is not necessary but it's good practice to make all your visible classes a subclass of the Sprite class, so you can add your game objects to `pygame.sprite.Group` and take advantages of some useful methods. (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to know. Thank you.